# 2nd Spinner which was created by 1st Spinner, should update textview

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

The 1st spinner adds the array list for the 2nd spinner based on the selected item. The textview always updates to the first item of the 2nd spinner whatever the selection of the 1st Spinner, however it doesn't update when selecting another item from the 2nd spinner such as the second item, so do the variables "emailname" and "emailto" even though the "emailto" variable has the same value throughout the rest of activity. The "emailname" proves it's not the other "emailto" as it doesn't change the value according to the rest of the items from the 2nd Spinner.

The activity works but the values aren't changing.

I tried adding runOnUiThread outside/inside if statements, made the t1.setValue alone outside with runOnUiThread. Didn't work.

I added a s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); It made the selected item of the 2nd spinner always stuck to the first item.

**StudentAppointmentActivity.java**

```
package com.example.collegeinfobotjava;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class StudentAppointmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner s1,s2;
    TextView t1;
    Button b1;
    EditText e1;
    ImageButton bck;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseauth;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    String uid,emailfrom,emailto,dep,emailnameto;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.studentappointment);


        t1 = findViewById(R.id.textviewwhomname);
        e1 = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextMultiLine);
        s1 = findViewById(R.id.spinnerdepartment);
        s2 = findViewById(R.id.spinnertowhom);
        b1 = findViewById(R.id.buttonstdappemailsend);
        bck = findViewById(R.id.imageButtonbck);


        firebaseauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        emailfrom = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
        uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

       

        b1.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (s1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("-")) {
                Toast.makeText(StudentAppointmentActivity.this, "Please choose which department", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else {
               sendEmail();
            }
        });

        bck.setOnClickListener(view -> goBack());

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sp1 = String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());


        if (sp1.contentEquals("Applied Sciences")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add("HoD");
            list.add("HoS-Applied Biology");
            list.add("HoS-Applied Chemistry");
            list.add("HoS-Environmental Sciences");
            list.add("HoS-Physics Unit");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            dep="Applied Sciences";

            if(s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HoD")){
                emailnameto="DR. AFRAA AL ADAWI";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
            if(s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HoS-Applied Biology")){
                emailnameto="Dr. Umaima Hamad Al Hoqaniya";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
            if(s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HoS-Applied Chemistry")){
                emailnameto="Dr. Wafa Mustafa Al-Lawati";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
            if(s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HoS-Environmental Sciences")){
                emailnameto="Dr. Suad Said Al-Kindi";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
            if(s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HoS-Physics Unit")){
                emailnameto="Mr. Shabbir Ahmed Nadeem";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
        }

        if (sp1.contentEquals("Business Studies")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add("HoD");
            list.add("HoS-HRM");
            list.add("HoS-Marketing");
            list.add("HoS-Accounting");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
            dep="Business Studies";
            if(s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HoD")){
                emailnameto="DR. BASSAM KHALIL HAMDAN TABASH";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
            if(s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HoS-HRM")){
                emailnameto="Dr. Fayza Salim Awlad Thani";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
            if(s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HoS-Marketing")){
                emailnameto="Ms. M. Seema";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
            if(s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HoS-Accounting")){
                emailnameto="Dr. Yousif Mohammed Al Balushi";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
        }

        if (sp1.contentEquals("Engineering")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add("HoD");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);
            dep="Engineering";

            if(s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HoD")){
                emailnameto="Dr. Yahya Obaid Bakheet Al Shamsi";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
        }

        if (sp1.contentEquals("Fashion Design")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add("HoD");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter4.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter4);
            dep="Fashion Design";
            if(s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HoD")){
                emailnameto="MS. SALWA SULTAN MOHAMMED AL-HABSI";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
        }

        if (sp1.contentEquals("Information Technology")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add("HoD");
            list.add("PC-Database");
            list.add("PC-Networking");
            list.add("PC-Software Engineering");
            list.add("PC-Internet and E-Security");
            list.add("PC-Information Systems");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter5 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter5.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter5.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter5);
            dep="Information Technology";
            if(s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HoD")){
                emailnameto="DR. HUDA AL SHUAILY";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
            if(s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("PC-Database")){
                emailnameto="Mr. Gregorio A. Dela Cruz Jr.";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
            if(s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("PC-Networking")){
                emailnameto="Mr. Russell Diona";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
            if(s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("PC-Software Engineering")){
                emailnameto="Imad Al Barwani";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
            if(s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("PC-Internet and E-Security")){
                emailnameto="Mr. Muhammed Raheez";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
            if(s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("PC-Information Systems")){
                emailnameto="Dr. Muna Saif Humaid Al Rahbi";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
        }

        if (sp1.contentEquals("Pharmacy")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add("HoD");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter6 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter6.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter6.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter6);
            dep="Pharmacy";
            if(s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HoD")){
                emailnameto="DR. MUNA ARIF MANSOOR AL JUMA";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
        }

        if (sp1.contentEquals("Photography")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add("HoD");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter7 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter7.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter7.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter7);
            dep="Photography";
            if (s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HoD")) {
                emailnameto="MR. BEN DEGEDEH";
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto="16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om";
            }
        }



    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }


    public void goBack(){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),StudentHomeActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    protected void sendEmail() {

        DatabaseReference databaseforeignReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("student");

        databaseforeignReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String stdid=dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("sid").getValue().toString();


         databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("appointment").child(uid).push();
        HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
        userMap.put("department", dep);
        userMap.put("discussed", e1.getText().toString());
        userMap.put("to_whom", emailnameto);
        userMap.put("studentid", stdid);
        databaseReference.setValue(userMap);

                String mEmail = emailto;
                String mSubject = "Appointment with "+stdid+" Student";
                String mMessage = e1.getText().toString();


                JavaMailAPI javaMailAPI = new JavaMailAPI(StudentAppointmentActivity.this, mEmail, mSubject, mMessage);

                javaMailAPI.execute();
                Toast.makeText(StudentAppointmentActivity.this, "Submitted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }

        });

    }
}
```

**studentappointment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonstdappemailsend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:text="Setup"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextMultiLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewdiscussed" />


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerdepartment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="162dp"
        android:entries="@array/department"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnertowhom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="67dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textviewwhomname"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textviewtowhom" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewstdappdep"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:text="Department"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/spinnerdepartment"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewtowhom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="379dp"
        android:text="To"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewdiscussed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewwhomname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonstdappemailsend"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Timing : Thursday, 10am -12 noon \nNote: Each student will take only 10 minutes.\nPlease make your appointment two (2) days before setting it up."
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewdiscussed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Items to be Discussed:"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinnerdepartment" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonbck"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.207"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/abc_vector_test" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonstdappemailsend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:text="Setup"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextMultiLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewdiscussed" />


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerdepartment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="162dp"
        android:entries="@array/department"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnertowhom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="67dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textviewwhomname"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textviewtowhom" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewstdappdep"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:text="Department"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/spinnerdepartment"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewtowhom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="379dp"
        android:text="To"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewdiscussed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewwhomname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonstdappemailsend"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Timing : Thursday, 10am -12 noon \nNote: Each student will take only 10 minutes.\nPlease make your appointment two (2) days before setting it up."
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewdiscussed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Items to be Discussed:"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinnerdepartment" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonbck"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.207"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/abc_vector_test" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Example 1:
[A1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZZ5n.png)
[A2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmGyu.png)

Example 2:
[B1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tfkB.png)
[B2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aemYC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you only set OnItemSelectedListener for the first spinner. You also have to set OnItemSelectedListener  for the second spinner.

```
s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

After that you have to handle OnItemSelectedListener with spinner ids.

```
  @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (parent.getId() == R.id.spinnerdepartment) {
            //Do whatever you want when item selected from the first spinner
        } else {
            //Do whatever you want when item selected from the second spinner
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
```

Instead of implementing OnItemSelectedListener, you can also set OnItemSelectedListener like below without implementing OnItemSelectedListener for your class:

```
s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
```

You also use same codes for sitiuations (for example setting adapter etc). I suggest use methods for same codes and handle variants inside methods. Your codes will look much cleaner and it will be easy to read and handle.

```
public class StudentAppointmentActivity  extends AppCompatActivity{

    Spinner s1,s2;
    TextView t1;
    Button b1;
    EditText e1;
    ImageButton bck;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseauth;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    String uid,emailfrom,emailto,dep,emailnameto;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.studentappointment);


        t1 = findViewById(R.id.textviewwhomname);
        e1 = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextMultiLine);
        s1 = findViewById(R.id.spinnerdepartment);
        s2 = findViewById(R.id.spinnertowhom);
        b1 = findViewById(R.id.buttonstdappemailsend);
        bck = findViewById(R.id.imageButtonbck);

        firebaseauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        emailfrom = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
        uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        b1.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (s1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("-")) {
                Toast.makeText(StudentAppointmentActivity.this, "Please choose which department", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else {
                sendEmail();
            }
        });

        bck.setOnClickListener(view -> goBack());

        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                setAdapter(listForS2(position));
                dep = deps(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                emailnameto = emailNameTo(s1.getSelectedItemPosition()).get(position);
                t1.setText(emailnameto);
                emailto = emailTo(s1.getSelectedItemPosition()).get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void setAdapter(List<String> list) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    private String deps(int position) {
        return position == 0 ? "Applied Sciences" : position == 1 ? "Business Studies" : position == 2 ? "Engineering" : position == 3
                ? "Fashion Design" : position == 4 ? "Information Technology" : position == 5 ? "Pharmacy" : "Photography";
    }

    private List<String> emailNameTo(int position) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (position == 0) {
            list.add("DR. AFRAA AL ADAWI");
            list.add("Dr. Umaima Hamad Al Hoqaniya");
            list.add("Dr. Wafa Mustafa Al-Lawati");
            list.add("Dr. Suad Said Al-Kindi");
            list.add("Mr. Shabbir Ahmed Nadeem");
        } else if (position == 1) {
            list.add("DR. BASSAM KHALIL HAMDAN TABASH");
            list.add("Dr. Fayza Salim Awlad Thani");
            list.add("Ms. M. Seema");
            list.add("Dr. Yousif Mohammed Al Balushi");
        } else if (position == 2) {
            list.add("Dr. Yahya Obaid Bakheet Al Shamsi");
        } else if (position == 3) {
            list.add("MS.SALWA SULTAN MOHAMMED AL -HABSI");
        }else if(position == 4){
            list.add("DR. HUDA AL SHUAILY");
            list.add("Mr. Gregorio A. Dela Cruz Jr.");
            list.add("Mr. Russell Diona");
            list.add("Imad Al Barwani");
            list.add("Mr. Muhammed Raheez");
            list.add("Dr. Muna Saif Humaid Al Rahbi");
        }else if(position == 5){
            list.add("DR. MUNA ARIF MANSOOR AL JUMA");
        }else{
            list.add("MR. BEN DEGEDEH");
        }
        return list;
    }

    private List<String> emailTo(int position) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (position == 0) {
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
        } else if (position == 1) {
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
        } else if (position == 2) {
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
        } else if (position == 3) {
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
        }else if(position == 4){
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
        }else if(position == 5){
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
        }else{
            list.add("16j15144@stu.hct.edu.om");
        }
        return list;
    }

    private List<String> listForS2(int position) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (position == 0) {
            list.add("HoD");
            list.add("HoS-Applied Biology");
            list.add("HoS-Applied Chemistry");
            list.add("HoS-Environmental Sciences");
            list.add("HoS-Physics Unit");
        } else if (position == 1) {
            list.add("HoD");
            list.add("HoS-HRM");
            list.add("HoS-Marketing");
            list.add("HoS-Accounting");
        } else if (position == 4) {
            list.add("HoD");
            list.add("PC-Database");
            list.add("PC-Networking");
            list.add("PC-Software Engineering");
            list.add("PC-Internet and E-Security");
            list.add("PC-Information Systems");
        } else {
            list.add("HoD");
        }
        return list;
    }

    public void goBack(){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),StudentHomeActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    protected void sendEmail() {
        DatabaseReference databaseforeignReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("student");

        databaseforeignReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String stdid=dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("sid").getValue().toString();

                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("appointment").child(uid).push();
                HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                userMap.put("department", dep);
                userMap.put("discussed", e1.getText().toString());
                userMap.put("to_whom", emailnameto);
                userMap.put("studentid", stdid);
                databaseReference.setValue(userMap);

                String mEmail = emailto;
                String mSubject = "Appointment with "+stdid+" Student";
                String mMessage = e1.getText().toString();

                JavaMailAPI javaMailAPI = new JavaMailAPI(StudentAppointmentActivity.this, mEmail, mSubject, mMessage);

                javaMailAPI.execute();
                Toast.makeText(StudentAppointmentActivity.this, "Submitted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }

        });

    }
}
```